# Uploading User Details from an excel file using pandas in python to postgres Database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pandas

I am uploading user details(username,email,password) from a .csv file to postgres DB using pandas in python. It is all fine till the dataframe gets generated but once I run the code for uploading the user details the substring-"@gmail.com" from their emai-id gets converted to/stored as lowercase in postgres DB. 
This is the code that I have written in python shell of a django application -

```
>>>import sys
>>>from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>>from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>>import pandas as pd

>>>User = get_user_model()

>>>df=pd.read_excel('set_A_results_748_web.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1',parse_cols=(0,3,4))
```

df.head()

[Dataframe First 10 rows Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIIgE.png)

```
>>>users = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]

>>>for name, email, password in users:
    try:
        print ('Creating user {0}.'.format(name))
        user = User.objects.create_user(name=name, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        assert authenticate(name=name, password=password)
        print ('User {0} successfully created.'.format(name))

    except:
        print ('There was a problem creating the user: {0}.  Error: {1}.' \
            .format(name, sys.exc_info()[1]))
```

[Postgres User Table Data Screenshot After Uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4vQi.png)

As shown in the output (first 10 rows of dataframe df) the email ids of every user is acc to the data in excel file but when I upload them to auth_user table in my postgres DB the latter part of email gets converted to lowercase.

Example: The E-mail address of row 6 (Dipak Shah) would be stored as `DIPAK.13ME57@gmail.com` whereas it should be stored as is i.e. `DIPAK.13ME57@GMAIL.COM`. This creates a problem in application as the users scores alongwith other details are stored in another scores table which I upload separately through a Kettle transformation. So for records which have email mismatch because of case mismatch there would be no data in the scores table.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong or what can I do to avoid this.Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with postgres, it's django that is [normalizing the email address](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L23) when a new user [is created](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L147), as the host part of an email address is case insensitive. Whether the name part is case sensitive usually depends on the mail server.

If you really need to use the email address as a matching criteria, then you should also apply the same normalization to those other addresses.

Edit:

It seems that this normalization is only applied in `create_user()`, if you later set the email address by using `user.email = 'SOMEBODY@EXAMPLE.ORG'` then it won't be applied. But I'd not rely too much on that, such a different behaviour could be seen as a bug and corrected in a future version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I converted all the email-ids to lowercase before uploading scores data to DB through Kettle transformation. Also I normalized the entire e-mail ID of the user(instead of just domain part) by defining my own Python class which extends BaseUserManager class in django.contrib.auth.base_user so that in both he tables email is stored in lowercase.